Windows 10 сбрасывает регион и формат даты для конкретного пользователя
Мне нужно сменить регион Россия на UK, но при каждой перезагрузки это всё сбрасывается. Вот что я пытался:
В параметрах сменить.
В панели управления - региональные стандарты.
Через powershell.
И даже через реестр.
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\Geo
name = GB
nation = 242

Более того, я пытался запретить системе изменять что-либо в этой ветке. Поставил только чтение, и даже так после перезапуска всё слетает обратно. Причём после 1-2 секунды запуска профиля сбрасывается. Если выйти из системы а не перезапускать то ничего не сбрасывается.
Вариантов что делать больше нет. Разве что переезжать на новый профиль, но как я перенесу всё, тоже самое что переустановлю систему, разницы 0. Уже пытался сменить директорию для нового профиля чтобы читал старый, но смысл.
Windows 10 Только Английский.
21H2
